# Append key/value pair to object

Tags: javascript

So, I have

```
{
  'A': {
    'B': 1
  },
  'B': {
    'A': 1
  }
}
```

And now I need to add more keys into 'B' so it would output

```
{
  'A': {
    'B': 1
  },
  'B': {
    'A': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 4
  }
}
```

The final result needs to be a similar object and not an array. Obviously .push(), .splice, etc, does not work.

How do I do this?

Comment: `a.B.C = 2;`, `a.B.D = 4;` or you want a general solution? If yes, what are the requirements?

Comment: That outputs `B:...` instead of `'B':...`.

Comment: @Swift-R It's the same identifier. But if you want, you can do `JSON.stringify` on the object to turn it into a proper JSON. Please look at Ziki's link. There are a lot of interesting ideas there.

Comment: Forgot to mention that A/B/C... comes from a variable and also that it's not letters but numbers. so `{ '1': { '2': 1 }, '2': { '1': 5, '3': 7, '4': 5 } }`

Comment: Again, the same idea: `a[2][3] = 7;`, `a[2][4] = 5;` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If A/B/C is coming from the variables then,
a[var1][var2]=var3;
in that way you have to design a logic , just to keep you objects according to your requirements.